# E2 Visa company converted from LLC to C-Corp

Tags: usa, immigration

I'm just about to apply for a E2 visa for my LLC corp formed in Wyoming. I've been accepted into a startup accelerator program that requires us to be a C-Corp. Will changing the companies structure from a LLC to a C-Corp affect my visa?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if changing your company's structure from LLC to C-Corp just before the visa application is filed will affect the likelihood of a visa being granted?

Comment: Hey David, no I'm asking if after I have had the LLC E2 approved whether converting would cause it to be revoked or something similar.  Obviously I want to be 100% sure not to do anything negative to affect the visa if I get it.

Comment: The action you're planning to take — converting your LLC to a C-corporation — will happen *before* you apply for the E2 visa, because if you don't take that action, then your company doesn't qualify. I think you can only make the change, file the application, and tell the truth.

Comment: Hey David, sorry why does my corporation not qualify otherwise?

Comment: Because you said in your original question "...that requires us to be a C-Corp." (pause) Oh, you meant that *the accelerator program* requires you to be a C-Corp. I apologize. I don't have experience with E2 visas, and don't know if the applicant firm must be or must not be of any particular type.

Comment: Yep it's the accelerator not the visa.  Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: You're welcome, I wasn't worth much here. Good luck with your process.